# Zoom SDK 2,3,5 Integration error (You have been limit by zoom, verfy recaptcha and try again)

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, zoom-sdk

I am trying to integrate zoom web SDK 2.3.5 in my Vue app with the Laravel as a backend but getting an error while joining the meeting.

here is the error message,

1. You have been limiting by zoom, verfy recaptcha and try again, open https://zoom.us
2. Failed to join the meeting.

I followed the zoom doc but got no success.

Thanks for considering.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answer:

the issue was with sdkKey, it should be the JWT API key, not the SDK key.

when I replace the sdkKey with the apiKey it worked fine.

thanks